# Invalid template file: 'switch/languages.phtml' in module Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-community

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template
> file: 'switch/languages.phtml' in module: 'Epoint_SwisspostApi'
> block's name: 'store_language'

**In the given below i add all xml**

**module.xml in the given below**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">  
    <module name="Epoint_SwisspostApi" setup_version="1.0.1"/>
</config>
```

**events.xml in the given below**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="model_delete_after">
        <observer name="epoint_model_delete_after" instance="Epoint\SwisspostApi\Observer\AfterModelDeleteObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Email_template in the given below**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:Magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
<template id="logging_email_template" label="Logging Email"file="logging_email_form.html" type="html"module="Epoint_SwisspostApi" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**di.xml in the given below**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="connect" xsi:type="object">Epoint\SwisspostApi\Console\Command\ConnectCommand</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <preference for="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" type="Epoint\SwisspostApi\Block\Switcher"/>
</config>
```

Comment: give xml defined block code..

Comment: Please share xml.

Comment: please never mind. I am new in magneto platform. where need to define block code. thank you in advance @Mitrajsinhvaghela

Comment: please share xml wherever you have written code containing 'switch/languages.phtml'

Comment: <?php

namespace Epoint\SwisspostApi\Block;

class Switcher extends \Magento\Store\Block\Switcher
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getTargetStorePostData(\Magento\Store\Model\Store $store, $data = [])
    {
        $data[\Magento\Store\Api\StoreResolverInterface::PARAM_NAME] = $store->getCode();
        $url = $this->getUrl('stores/store/switch');
        return $this->_postDataHelper->getPostData(
            $url,
            $data
        );
    }
}

Comment: please edit the question with the xml file code. so we get idea and let you know.